# Specifying a type in inline event - typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have an inline event for a input text, updating a variable:

`on:input={(event) => (title = event.target?event.target.value:"")}`

It does work as intended but ts complains: *Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' *

I tried these variations with no success:

`on:input={(event as HtmlInputElement) => (title = event.target?event.target.value:"")}`

`on:input={(event: { HTMLInputElement }) => (title = event.target?event.target.value:"")}`

`on:input={(event:HTMLInputElement) => (title = event.target?event.target.value:"")}`

`on:input={event => (title = event.target?(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value:"")}`

What is the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.target` can be a different element for certain events (those that bubble).
Use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead, it should have the type of the element the event handler is on.

```html
<input on:input={e => title = e.currentTarget.value} ... />
```

In this specific case, if you want to synchronize a variable, you can also just use [`bind:`](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#bind-property):

```html
<input bind:value={title} />
```

You currently [*cannot* use TS syntax in the template](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4701).